# Google Play Reject: Is there a way to use Firebase Analytics without using background location?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play-services, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I've uploaded my react-native app to Google Play and it has been rejected due to using background location permission.

[The rejection email from Google Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwfTS.png)

Google Play won't allow any background location usage without valid proof of using it, which is a thing I cannot even prove.

After drilling it down, I found out that the only entity that's using this permission is Firebase Analytics (I guess it's the Google Play Services plugin).

Does anybody know how to bypass it?

I'm using the most updated react-native & expo versions.

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: How do you find that the Firebase Analytics is using background location permission?